# How to replace parts of a string in Python using replace and slicing operator?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have story in a String for example:

```
my_string = "Once upon a time, there was a boy. He went to school and enrolled to a course ACC 2011, Later he enrolled to another course ACC 4589. He did well in both of the courses"
```

And I have the following variable
`course_code = 1111`

I need a python script that will search for ACC on my_string and then it would replace the course code with the value of course_code which is 1111

So the final output would be:

```
    my_string = "Once upon a time, there was a boy. He went to school and enrolled to a course ACC 1111, Later he enrolled to another course ACC 1111. He did well in both of the courses"
```

Can I do something like the following?

```
my_string.replace(ACC ****, ACC + course_code)
```

Comment: @Sujay
Actually I would like to know how exactly I can search all the courses starts with ACC

So in the example I need to find ACC 2019 & ACC 4589 so that I can update them with ACC 1111

Comment: You should go by @Chris 's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `re.sub`:

```
import re
course_code = 1111
re.sub("(ACC) \d+", f"\\1 {course_code}", my_string)
```

Output:

```
'Once upon a time, there was a boy. He went to school and enrolled to a course ACC 1111, Later he enrolled to another course ACC 1111. He did well in both of the courses'
```

As per the comment, if the digits are wrapped by the double quotes, you can include it in the `pattern`:

```
test = 'ACC "2000"'
course_code = 1111
re.sub("(ACC) \"\d+\"", f"\\1 {course_code}", test)
```

Output:

```
'ACC 1111'
```

Comment: @Sam Which version of python are you using?

Comment: 3.7. Actually the above example worked, thanks Chris! But I am trying to update an excel cell following this and it is not working..Let me look into this I will keep you posted

Comment: @Sam If you are dealing with an excel file and seeking for a way to alter many cells, do look for `pandas.read_excel` and start from there

Comment: key=999999
re.sub("(acc) \d+", f"\\1 {key}",worksheet.cell(row=r, column=12).value)

So I am trying to update the above excel cell using re but the value of the cell is not updating

Comment: @Sam Well did you assign the replaced string back to the cell?

Comment: I will take a look at pandas..do you have any idea why the above line is not working?

Comment: Hi @Chris I found the issue. So In the string If I have ACC "4819" the above code would not work re.sub("(ACC) \d+", f"\\1 {course_code}", my_string)

The above example worked because I had ACC 4819. Can you please guide what to update to support ACC "4819"?

Comment: So the original string would be this:

my_string = "Once upon a time, there was a boy. He went to school and enrolled to a course ACC "2011", Later he enrolled to another course ACC "4589". He did well in both of the courses"

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris!